# Stripe Checkout - How to handle user id with webhooks

Tags: stripe-payments

I am currently adding the Stripe checkout to my application. My goal is really to have at least as code as possible.

The [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscription?ui=checkout#provision-and-monitor) says I need to handle at least three different webhook types:

- checkout.session.completed
- invoice.paid
- invoice.payment_failed

I try to avoid handling any customers in Stripe and I think it is not necessary with the checkout component.

However, I still need the user id in the webhooks to update the states accordingly.

When creating the session on the backend I'll add the field `client_reference_id`.

For the state `checkout.session.completed` I get this field and everything is fine.

For `invoice.paid` I don't get it and I need to use `subscription_data.metadata` in the session to get this data.

For `invoice.payment_failed` I don't know how to get it or how to test it with the CLI because I can't add metadata and I cannot add the `client_reference_id`.

Do you have an idea what the best practice here is and how I should implement that? Or should I really handle a customer in Stripe as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple different ways you can handle this -

- If also set `client_reference_id` in `subscription_data.metadata`, you can still get it from the `invoice.paid` and `invoice.payment_failed` events by [retrieving the Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/retrieve) found at `subscription` on the Invoice (see [api ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-subscription)).
- You could change your database to store the relationship between a Stripe Customer and a `client_reference_id`. When you get an `invoice.paid` or `invoice.payment_failed` event you would grab the Customer ID and the information in your database would allow you to tie it back to the correct `client_reference_id`.

Comment: The Stripe customer and client_reference_id mapping will be done in the first call to checkout.session.completed. What would you do in the case during the first call invoice.paid gets called before the mapping in the database is complete?

Comment: @AbdulAziz That's something you'd have to account for in your code - you could have your webhook endpoint immediately return a 200 response for the `invoice.paid` event (since Stripe expects a response quickly) and then queue that event up on your end and wait to process it until your database has been udpated

Comment: You could also model your data so that it doesn't matter. Store the mapping of your app's "client_reference_id" -> stripes "customer_id" and model your subscription state from stripes "customer_id" -> subscription data.